# mysql query with Or, Left Join, Outer Left Join, AND ON and IS NULL

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join, isnull

I'm trying to pull records from one table (workers) that matches 2 of 5 status options (Active or Pending), within a specific date range, and I want to identify from a separate table (work_earn) a specific payment method (ACH), and where they have not yet been paid (IS NULL)

I've tried a few different ways, but I keep getting a syntax error. What am I missing? Here are two queries that I tried, with corresponding error messages.

```
SELECT * FROM workers 
WHERE (status = 'Active') OR (status= 'Pending') 
and date >= '$Start' AND date <= '$End' AND 
LEFT JOIN work_earn method = 'ACH' AND ON work_earn.wid IS NULL
```

ERROR

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN work_earn method = 'ACH' AND ON work_earn.wid IS NULL LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
>
> ---

```
SELECT * FROM workers 
WHERE status = 'Active' OR  'Pending' and date >= '2018-04-18' AND date <= '2018-03-18' AND 
LEFT JOIN work_earn method = 'ACH' AND ON work_earn.wid IS NULL
```

ERROR

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN work_earn method = 'ACH' AND ON work_earn.wid IS NULL LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Left Join should be before the Where clause. Then fix up the rest of your query.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this:

SELECT * FROM work_earn, workers LEFT JOIN work_earn method = 'ACH' AND ON work_earn.wid IS NULL WHERE (status = 'Active') OR (status= 'Pending')  and date >= '2018-04-18' AND date <= '2018-03-18'

and got this:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'ACH' AND ON work_earn.mid IS NULL WHERE (status = 'Active') OR (status= '' at line 1

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors. Please see here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp how to left join.

Comment: **Why are you yelling, please read the edit help.** PS Please clarify via post edit, not via comment. And read & act on [mcve]. Note part of finding minimal code with the/a problem is finding maximal code without. And: Always google an error message & number with & without your particular names & code. Read all answers to learn of many ways it can arise. Also make sure you are properly parenthesizing your ANDs & ORs. And read an intro to SQL select & joins.